# Chain multiple "then" in jQuery.when

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I have a function that does something like this:

```
function do_something() {
    // some code

    return $.when(foo, bar, baz).then(do_something_else);
}

function do_something_else(_foo, _bar, _baz) {
    // do something else

    return /* the original inputs */;
}
```

So, when someone uses `do_something`, they can also chain more callbacks, like:

```
do_something().then(function(_foo_2, _bar_2, _baz_2) {
    console.log(_foo_2, _bar_2, _baz_2);
});
```

The problem is that I don't know how to bypass the original return from `do_something_else` to the anonymous function described. I don't want to receive a list, but positional arguments instead, so "when foo" inserts some value to do_something_else's _foo and then the same value goes to _foo_2.

How can I do it in JS?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Use an anonymous function inside of `.then` and pass the parameters that you want to pass. I'm replacing `.then` with `.done` because you don't need `.then` in this case.

```
function do_something() {
    // some code

    return $.when(foo, bar, baz).done(function(_foo_2, _bar_2, _baz_2){
        do_something_else.apply(this,_foo_2);
    });
}
```

.then actually creates a new deferred object and sends that to the chain. Since you didn't return anything from `.then`, the new deferred object has no arguments. See this example:

```
$.when($.Deferred().resolve(2), $.Deferred().resolve(4))
.then(function(a,b) { 
    console.log(a,b); // 2,4
    return $.Deferred().resolve(a,b,6);
}).then(function(a,b,c) { 
    console.log(a,b,c); // 2,4,6
});
```

If you instead just used `.done`, it would work as expected.

```
$.when($.Deferred().resolve(2), $.Deferred().resolve(4))
.done(function(a,b) { 
    console.log(a,b);
}).done(function(a,b) { 
    console.log(a,b);
});
```

The most common use for `.then` is chaining ajax requests:

```
$.ajax({...}).then(function(){
    return $.ajax({...});
}).then(function(){
    return $.ajax({...});
}).then(function(){
    return $.ajax({...});
}).then(function(){
    return $.ajax({...});
});
```

which can also be easily done in a loop. Each `.then` will have access to the returned data from the previous request.

Comment: What's the difference between .done and .then in this case? I'm running [this example](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5823503)

Comment: `.then` will create a new deferred and add that to the chain. The next thing you do on the chain, such as `.done` or `.then`, will only have access to what was returned from the previous `.then`.

Comment: @KevinB: Is that how jQuery implemented it? Sad :( In the original proposal, the new promise is resolved with the original results if none is returned from the `.then` callback.

Comment: @FelixKling That's what i thought it was originally too, but further testing shows that isn't the case. I'm kinda confused atm about it. http://jsfiddle.net/75L9a/2/

Comment: @FelixKling After further reading, i see where teh confusion is. The functionality you are referring to was added in 1.5 and removed in 1.8 when `.then` over-took `.pipe`'s functionality. .then's arguments are now done and fail *filters* rather than callbacks.